# Изменить типа поля с varchar2 на blob

Tags: oracle, база-данных, sql

Есть таблица с данными, в которой есть поле типа `varchar2(4000)`. Как поменять поле на тип `blob`, при этом не потеряв данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а уже сам нагуглил, но вдруг кому пригодится)

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD clobfield CLOB;
UPDATE table_name SET clobfield = varcharfield;
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN varcharfield;
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN clobfield TO varcharfield;
```